# Page Object Model - drop down menu

Tags: java, selenium

I have website which is build on old javascript code.

it has two section and single URL which is not changing after any interaction.
main section - which shows some option which can be click or enter some data.
another section - which is nothing but drop down. it is possible that there is nothing except some static content. this drop down section is based on main section page.

generally, sequence of call can be
1. click something on the main section of the page. nothing on dropdown section
2. now drop down section change. select something there. change in main section
3. enter value and click on main section. change on drop down section
4. selection on drop down. update on main section
5. and so on

I am using page object model
I have created Page Object for main section on every page

question here is
how to handle the drop down. this drop down are changing on most of the page.
basically there is drop down or there is nothing.

remember, URL is not changing though HTML is changing based on interaction.
Thanks

Comment: Code trials? Relevant HTML? Any error?

Comment: Error is nullpointer exception for RemoteWebDriver.findElement..question is more about how the page object work specifically .@FindBy...because website URL is not changing.but element on the page is changing after interaction. so is there a refresh or I need to create new object everytime

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow way:
 1. Create only parent element of dropdown using @FindBy.
 2. Use this element in the methods, that handles the dropdown + paths to needed sub elements, F.E:

Dropdown in html:

```
<span id="mainDropDown">
  …..
   <span index="3">Item to click</span>
</span>
```

Java code (possible have mistakes since I coding in other framework now):

```
@FindBy(id="mainDropDown")
private WebElement dropDown;
public void expandDropdown(){
    dropDown.Click();
    werifyIfExpand();
}

publick void selectItemByIndexValue(int index){
    dropDown.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@index= '" + index + "']"));
}
```